# SP services multiple lookup

Tags: spservices

I've managed to get information from a multiple lookup with the line below, however it returns a single string. I need to compare each item to a known path. i.e. IT, IT/sub1, IT/sub2 etc. so individual items need testing.

```
var lookup = ($(this).attr("ows_PublishTo_x003A_shARe_x0020"));
```

output :

```
1;#/sites/ITDEV;#3;#/sites/ITDEV/TeamN
```

Is there a method I can utilise to make this more robust or will I need to manipulate the string into an array and test each element?

Answer (score 0):

Check this comment from Marc:

> In my test environment, what I see in an Audiences column is
>   semi-colon separated values. (Sharepoint often uses this convention
>   for multi-select columns.)  You're trying to treat that single text
>   string as if it is an array, which it isn't.  You'll need to use the
>   split function to convert the values to an array.
>
> Something like this:
>
> var audienceValueArray = itemAudience.split(";");

https://spservices.codeplex.com/discussions/209567.

I don't think SPServices provides any method to read lookup values, so you may have to use javascript `split`